# Knife Container issue

Tags: docker, chef-infra

My Docker, chefDk and workstation all on same node and chef server on different machine

After running 
`knife container init demo/apache2 -r recipe["some_recipe"]`

It create a Docker-file and Docker Context with demo/apache2 tag name having Ubuntu image.

After this ,when i run `knife container build demo/apache2`
it throw the following error

```
[2015-02-27T11:05:32+00:00] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/secure/client.pem is not present - registering
[2015-02-27T11:05:32+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: 10.88.200.224 - hostname does not match the server certificate

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "demo-apache2-build"
================================================================================

[2015-02-27T11:05:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-02-27T11:05:32+00:00] ERROR: hostname does not match the server certificate
[2015-02-27T11:05:32+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your server certificates are not in place. Please make sure you followed the instructions to properly install the Chef DK.

```
http://docs.chef.io/client/install_workstation.html
-->add the missing "client.pem"
--> and then do a "knife ssl check"
```